# How to handle keyPressEvent on desktop in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

How to handle keyPressEvent on desktop or any other window in PyQt4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt4.5 introduced a new style API. You could use:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.onClicked)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But can I handle event when I click on desktop or any other window?

Comment: You can handle that in self.oncClicked method.

Comment: Can you provide me more information about it? I'm newbie in python and I need to handle key when user press it without show my application window. Can you show me example how to do it? (Also, sorry for my bad English) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this method `QWidget.keyPressEvent (self, QKeyEvent)` ?

If yes, example for control then any key in keyboard pressed:

```
def keyPressEvent (self, eventQKeyEvent):
    key = eventQKeyEvent.key()
    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_F1:
        print 'Help'
    elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_F5:
        print 'Reload'
```

And this is reference of list key available for handle in PyQt4

**Reference:** http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#Key-enum

---

Regards,